# can not get the ip address of a remote computer

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, servlets

i have a requirement that only one user will be allowed to log in using one login id and password that means not two users will be allowed to login using the same username and id.so i thought to make a field in my Db to store the ipaddress.Suppose A has logged in then his ip address will be stored in Db and now if B wants to login then he will get alert that this user has already logged in and the ip address is A's ipaddress.and for that purpose i am using

```
    <%@ page import="java.net.*" %>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<%

out.println("remote address  "+request.getRemoteAddr());
 out.println("remote host  "+request.getRemoteHost());
 out.println("remote port "+request.getRemotePort());
 out.println("remote user  "+request.getRemoteUser());
//out.println(InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress());
out.println(request.getRemoteAddr());
//out.println(InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress().toString());
%>
</body>
</html>
```

but i am not getting the exact ipaddress.please tell me how to get the ipaddress.if you think this way of storing ipadddress in Db and alerting to duplicate user is not wise then yours suggestions are also welcome

```
remote address 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 remote host 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 remote port 38059 remote user null 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1
```

Comment: if anybody do not like the question they can leave comment here but downvoting without proper reason is not good

Comment: What did `request.getRemoteAddr()` give you? Are you running this application inside a company's intranet or is it accessible from outside as well?

Comment: @w4rumy i have edited the question and the output is also added

Comment: @w4rumy i am running it in intranet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, `request.getRemoteAddr()` did not work for you. It is quite impossible to say why without knowing the company's network you are working in.

However, you do not even need the IP-address for that. Just keep a flag if the user is currently logged in:

```
User | logged in?
-----+------------
 A   |    Yes
 B   |    No
 C   |    No
```

Now, if a user tries to login, check if he/she is already logged in. If so, display an error message and avoid login.

You need to reset this flag

- When the user logs out (clicking the "logout" button)
- After the session times out (you can use a [HttpSessionListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionListener.html) for that), in case that the user did not click "logout". **Note:** If you have a high session timeout (like 30 minutes), and the user forgets to click "logout", he/she will not be able to login for the rest of the session.
- After the application is redeployed, if all sessions are destroyed then.

Comment: thanks for the answer but this way will look simple. if getting the ipaddress is not possible can it be done to automatically logout. i mean to say that suppose A is logged in with username X and now when B tries to log in with same username X then at A side logout will happen automatically and if a tried to do something then it will take him to login page. can it be possible.Please free to ask me if you could not understand what i mean to say

Comment: @javaL Of course this can be done, but this is a very different question. You could store the `jsessionid` as well which identifies the current "valid" session for a user and log him/ automatically out if he has a different `jsessionid`. Feel free to ask another question on Stackoverflow when you are getting into trouble implementing this.

Comment: i am not asking question because i am getting downvoting

Comment: @javaL If you can show your research effort and some coude you have tried, you probably won't get downvoted. And sorry, I will not do the work for you. It is not a feature that can be implemented within 2 minutes, it will take some time.